# ElasticSearch cluster won't recover

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

My team and I have been fighting with elastic search for a long time and I'm wondering if someone can help. We're running ES 2.1 on ubuntu docker containers on a kubernetes cluster. All of the nodes mount the same drive for logs and data storage. The cluster itself works fine, until a node goes down, or we rebuild the cluster, then it can never restore itself on it's own. Right now for instance I killed all of the instances and when the came back up it restored the shards to 44% and won't go any further. Usually we can get all of the shards loaded by deleting certain nodes and force assigning others

```
The logs only seem to yield: IllegalIndexShardStateException[CurrentState[RECOVERING] operations only allowed when shard state is one of [POST_RECOVERY, STARTED, RELOCATED]]  

UnavailableShardsException[[.marvel-es-2016.03.15][0] Primary shard is not active or isn't assigned to a known node. T imeout: [1m], request: org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkShardRequest@186bacfb]]
```

Here is my config:

```
cluster.name: Alice
security.manager.enabled: false
cluster.routing.allocation.enable: all
cluster.routing.allocation.allow_rebalance: always
indices.store.throttle.type: none
path.data: /data/data
path.logs: /data/logs
network.host: 0.0.0.0

script.inline: on
script.indexed: on
script.file: on

cloud:
  kubernetes:
      service: elasticsearch-cluster
      namespace: els

discovery:
  type: kubernetes

discovery.zen.minimum_master_node: 2
```

I'm also using the following init script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# /etc/init.d/elasticsearch -- startup script for Elasticsearch
#
# Written by Miquel van Smoorenburg <miquels@cistron.nl>.
# Modified for Debian GNU/Linux by Ian Murdock <imurdock@gnu.ai.mit.edu>.
# Modified for Tomcat by Stefan Gybas <sgybas@debian.org>.
# Modified for Tomcat6 by Thierry Carrez <thierry.carrez@ubuntu.com>.
# Additional improvements by Jason Brittain <jason.brittain@mulesoft.com>.
# Modified by Nicolas Huray for Elasticsearch <nicolas.huray@gmail.com>.
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          elasticsearch
# Required-Start:    $network $remote_fs $named
# Required-Stop:     $network $remote_fs $named
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Starts elasticsearch
# Description:       Starts elasticsearch using start-stop-daemon
### END INIT INFO

PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
NAME=elasticsearch
DESC="Elasticsearch Server"
DEFAULT=/etc/default/$NAME

if [ `id -u` -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "You need root privileges to run this script"
    exit 1
fi


. /lib/lsb/init-functions

if [ -r /etc/default/rcS ]; then
    . /etc/default/rcS
fi


# The following variables can be overwritten in $DEFAULT

# Run Elasticsearch as this user ID and group ID
ES_USER=ubuntu
ES_GROUP=ubuntu

# Directory where the Elasticsearch binary distribution resides
ES_HOME=/opt/elasticsearch

# Heap size defaults to 256m min, 1g max
# Set ES_HEAP_SIZE to 50% of available RAM, but no more than 31g
ES_HEAP_SIZE=4g

# Heap new generation
#ES_HEAP_NEWSIZE=

# max direct memory
#ES_DIRECT_SIZE=

# Additional Java OPTS
#ES_JAVA_OPTS=

# Maximum number of open files
MAX_OPEN_FILES=65535

# Maximum amount of locked memory
#MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY=

# Elasticsearch log directory
LOG_DIR=/data/logs

# Elasticsearch data directory
DATA_DIR=/data/data

# Elasticsearch configuration directory
CONF_DIR=/opt/elasticsearch/config

# Maximum number of VMA (Virtual Memory Areas) a process can own
MAX_MAP_COUNT=262144

# Path to the GC log file
#ES_GC_LOG_FILE=/var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log

# Elasticsearch PID file directory
PID_DIR="/var/run/elasticsearch"

# End of variables that can be overwritten in $DEFAULT

# overwrite settings from default file
if [ -f "$DEFAULT" ]; then
    . "$DEFAULT"
fi

# CONF_FILE setting was removed
if [ ! -z "$CONF_FILE" ]; then
    echo "CONF_FILE setting is no longer supported. elasticsearch.yml must be placed in the config directory and cannot be renamed."
    exit 1
fi

# Define other required variables
PID_FILE="$PID_DIR/$NAME.pid"
DAEMON=$ES_HOME/bin/elasticsearch
DAEMON_OPTS="-d -p $PID_FILE --default.path.home=$ES_HOME --default.path.logs=$LOG_DIR --default.path.data=$DATA_DIR --default.path.conf=$CONF_DIR"

export ES_HEAP_SIZE
export ES_HEAP_NEWSIZE
export ES_DIRECT_SIZE
export ES_JAVA_OPTS
export ES_GC_LOG_FILE
export JAVA_HOME

# Check DAEMON exists
test -x $DAEMON || exit 0

checkJava() {
    if [ -x "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" ]; then
        JAVA="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
    else
        JAVA=`which java`
    fi

    if [ ! -x "$JAVA" ]; then
        echo "Could not find any executable java binary. Please install java in your PATH or set JAVA_HOME"
        exit 1
    fi
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    checkJava

    if [ -n "$MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY" -a -z "$ES_HEAP_SIZE" ]; then
        log_failure_msg "MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY is set - ES_HEAP_SIZE must also be set"
        exit 1
    fi

    log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC"

    pid=`pidofproc -p $PID_FILE elasticsearch`
    if [ -n "$pid" ] ; then
        log_begin_msg "Already running."
        log_end_msg 0
        exit 0
    fi

    # Prepare environment
    mkdir -p "$LOG_DIR" "$DATA_DIR" && chown "$ES_USER":"$ES_GROUP" "$LOG_DIR" "$DATA_DIR"

    # Ensure that the PID_DIR exists (it is cleaned at OS startup time)
    if [ -n "$PID_DIR" ] && [ ! -e "$PID_DIR" ]; then
        mkdir -p "$PID_DIR" && chown "$ES_USER":"$ES_GROUP" "$PID_DIR"
    fi
    if [ -n "$PID_FILE" ] && [ ! -e "$PID_FILE" ]; then
        touch "$PID_FILE" && chown "$ES_USER":"$ES_GROUP" "$PID_FILE"
    fi

    if [ -n "$MAX_OPEN_FILES" ]; then
        ulimit -n $MAX_OPEN_FILES
    fi

    if [ -n "$MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY" ]; then
        ulimit -l $MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY
    fi

    if [ -n "$MAX_MAP_COUNT" -a -f /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count ]; then
        sysctl -q -w vm.max_map_count=$MAX_MAP_COUNT
    fi

    # Start Daemon
    start-stop-daemon -d $ES_HOME --start -b --user "$ES_USER" -c "$ES_USER" --pidfile "$PID_FILE" --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS
    return=$?
    if [ $return -eq 0 ]; then
        i=0
        timeout=10
        # Wait for the process to be properly started before exiting
        until { cat "$PID_FILE" | xargs kill -0; } >/dev/null 2>&1
        do
            sleep 1
            i=$(($i + 1))
            if [ $i -gt $timeout ]; then
                log_end_msg 1
                exit 1
            fi
        done
    fi
    log_end_msg $return
    exit $return
    ;;
  stop)
    log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC"

    if [ -f "$PID_FILE" ]; then
        start-stop-daemon --stop --pidfile "$PID_FILE" \
            --user "$ES_USER" \
            --quiet \
            --retry forever/TERM/20 > /dev/null
        if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
            log_progress_msg "$DESC is not running but pid file exists, cleaning up"
        elif [ $? -eq 3 ]; then
            PID="`cat $PID_FILE`"
            log_failure_msg "Failed to stop $DESC (pid $PID)"
            exit 1
        fi
        rm -f "$PID_FILE"
    else
        log_progress_msg "(not running)"
    fi
    log_end_msg 0
    ;;
  status)
    status_of_proc -p $PID_FILE elasticsearch elasticsearch && exit 0 || exit $?
    ;;
  restart|force-reload)
    if [ -f "$PID_FILE" ]; then
        $0 stop
        sleep 1
    fi
    $0 start
    ;;
  *)
    log_success_msg "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|force-reload|status}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm worried by this :

> All of the nodes mount the same drive for logs and data storage

Maybe I misunderstood what you said, but your nodes shouldn't share the same data folder. Each node need to write to their own data folder